# GUI netbeans, arrays and jlist

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jlist

we are a group of students trying to create a GUI in netbeans. We need a button to work, that takes the info from our jtextfield1(CPR) and checks if it suits one of the array numbers, and from that post some info in our jList1.
This is not completely done, as we dont know how to continue. We are getting a red line under "equals" with the error "Cannot find symbol". Any idea what the problem is?

DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.clear();

```
    String[] anArray;
    anArray = new String [3];


    anArray[0] = "260894-2931"; 
    anArray[1] = "200771-4672";
    anArray[2] = "290736-4960"; 
    if(CPR.equals = anArray[0]);
        System.out.println("CPR"+ anArray[0] + "Vaccineret af"+ "Vaccination:"+"Betalt gennem sygesikring");



    jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

Comment: it means that you have a compiler error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if(CPR.equals = anArray[0]);
```

is not valid in Java.I assume you wanted :

```
  if(CPR.getText().equals(anArray[0]));
```